# How does Xcode know which app to replace when updating

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been working on an app in Xcode (not submitted to the App Store or anything like that) that has a *lot* of very important data whose loss is insurmountable. The app has recently started crashing on startup; therefore, I have tried to update the code to Swift2 so that it works.

After having Xcode automatically update this app to the new version of Swift, I have been having a major issue: When I re-download the app using a cable plugged into the iMac and the iDevice, the new version of the app does not replace the old one––it adds another app to the device. Why would this be happening, and, more importantly, is there any way to fix that?

The point of this is to retrieve the data which was saved in UserDefaults to the previous version of the app. Hence, I'll do pretty much anything to get that data back.

It is absolutely imperative that I retrieve the data stored in UserDefaults; the data is not stored anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the key is the bundle ID. We have a main bundle ID for production and a second target with a different ID for testing. Pretty convenient to have different versions of the app on the same device.

The second thing you can check is that the version number in the new project is greater than the version on the original project.

To see what apps and versions are installed on your phone, go to Devices (Shift-Command-2). Select your phone from the list on the left and the manually installed apps will be listed near the bottom. Sometimes this gets covered by the Console messages so you might need to scroll down.

Here's what the Device Manager looks like--I deleted my console logs...
[image: Device Manager]

Here is the Installed Apps view. It is behind the console logs so you need to scroll down in the top area...

[image: Installed Apps]

Comment: The issue for me is that I don't know the version number of the old project or, more importantly, it's bundle identifier

Comment: Did you check Devices?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this so where is that? Is it on iTunesConnect?

Comment: From within Xcode, press Shift-Command-2 or you can click the Window menu and choose Devices.

Comment: And what does that tell me? The current bundle identifier of the app?

Comment: Added screenshots. Yes. it shows the bundle of the app plus the build number, rather than the version.

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is that I don't know the bundle identifier of my old project that was already on my device. I want to check what it is so that the new one can have the same ID and therefore replace it on my device--I just don't know how to check the old one's ID, as its project has been updated and the ID changed

Comment: Isn't the `identifier` there the device's ID, not the apps?

Comment: You must not be scrolling down. In the second screenshot, I'm showing the identifier for the app. In this case it is com.spookygroup.imjoy. The device's identifier (I removed) is up top.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your help and patience! +1 and √ <-- that's a check